# Unable to locate text field with type email with two attributes in page-object gem

Tags: page-object-gem

I am beginner in page-object.
I tried to locate "text field" using two attributes like this
text_field("user_name", {:class => 'title', :name => 'spree_user[email]'})

and html of text field is

But getting error : Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@class='title' and @name='spree_user[email]' and @type='text']"}

but the element exists on page.
The problem is it is taking type='text' by default as it looks from error message.But according to html of element type='email'. But when i locate this element using a single attribute it works fine.

Any suggestion would be helpful..

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the text field? Also, are you using Selenium-WebDriver or Watir-WebDriver?

Comment: I don't know how much of a difference it makes, but what if you specify the identifiers without the block?
'text_field(:user_name, :class => 'title, :name =>'spree_user[email]')'

Try that out and respond here, then we'll work on putting up and actual answer.

Comment: @Justin KO: html of text field<input class="title" id="spree_user_email" name="spree_user[email]" placeholder="Email" tabindex="1" type="email">

Comment: @Justin KO: Using Selenium-WebDriver and html of text field is <input class="title" id="spree_user_email" name="spree_user[email]" placeholder="Email" tabindex="1" type="email">
but by looking at error message, it seems that it is taking type='text' by default.That's why not able to locate element.
However when i locate this textfield with a single attribute, it is working fine.

Comment: @Jared_Casey: Although it should not be a difference but still I have tried both ways..

Comment: There is an issue on the Page Object Gem Github page for `text_field` only locating elements with type text - [Issue 214](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/214).

Answer (score 2):

So, the easy answer is use `id`:

```
text_field("user_name", id: "spree_user_email")
```

But these two should also work, if for some reason you don't want to use id:

```
text_field("user_name", class: "title", type: "email")

element("user_name", :input, class: "title", name: "spree_user[email]")
```

The first one defines the type attribute so it's not overwritten by default page-object action. The second is the round-about way of defining an element, and it doesn't append a type attribute to the selector.